# import with vue in an old project

Tags: html, vue.js, vue-component

I try to upgrade some of my "old project" interface element with some vue.

My old project is an php/html project without framework.
I make some test with vue-cli for different component for chart or for grid.

Now I want to integrate this component in my old project but the "import" of component doesn't work.

For example, in one page I need an ag-grid so I get ag grid vue.
But the basic
`import { AgGridVue } from 'ag-grid-vue';`
doesn't work because he can't get "ag-grid-vue".
It's not an vue app it's vue from html.

If I use `import { AgGridVue } from '/component/ag-grid-vue/main.js';` that's say "The requested module './component/ag-grid-vue/main.js' does not provide an export named 'AgGridVue'"

If I use `import AgGridVue from '/component/ag-grid-vue/main.js';` that's say "The requested module './component/ag-grid-vue/main.js' does not provide an export named 'default'"

I don't need the same component in my different page.
So the question is : How can I import my vue component ?

Answer (score 0):

if you are not using vue in your old project, then you can't use it. Alternatively, you can use `Vue cdn` and use `ag Grid cdn` as well.

https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/@ag-grid-community/vue

**html file**

```html
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <!-- I think you can put the component here -->
  </div>
</body>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ag-grid-community/vue@25.0.0/main.min.js"></script>

<script>
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue!'
  }
})
</script>
```

You can explore more from here.